# A webpage(for searching items) has a default result of an item in the db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a "Shopping Webpage" just to test SQL Injection (I'm trying to mock the webpage shown in Computerphile's "SQL Injection" video). Searching for the data isn't a problem, but the default result (when I refresh the page) is an item inside my db instead of nothing. Can you help me? Also only one item comes up when I have two items that match that search query.

Everything is new for me on php. I've seen a lot of Youtube tutorials and tried making new website codes just to check that the tutorial I took was right. But nothing really worked for me.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not 
connect");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "search_products") or die("Could not find the 
database");

$output = '';
$count = 0;

if (isset($_POST['searchq']))
{
    $search_query = $_POST['searchq'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE 
           '%$search_query%'") 
        or die("Could not search for the query");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0)
{
    $output = 'No Results';
}
else
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $stock = $row['instock'];

        $output = '<div> '.$name.' '.$price.' '.$stock.' </div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

<--This is my php code -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting only one item because of the below line

`$output = '<div> '.$name.' '.$price.' '.$stock.' </div>';`

The above line overrides the previous value. So replace it with below:

`$output .= '<div> '.$name.' '.$price.' '.$stock.' </div>';` (observe the dot after variable name).

The above line will concatenate each of the item. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change the following to see if helps
`if (isset($_POST['searchq']))` to `if (isset($_POST['searchq']) && !empty($_POST['searchq']))` 
$output should have ".=" instead of "=", you are simply replacing the new output with the old one.  You should concatinate to get all results.

Comment: Acceping the answer will help others too.